# gnome ppp installation without connection

Tags: package-management

Is there any way to install the gnome ppp package without an online connection. It opens in the software center but the install button is not active. I currently have wvdial package and gnome ppp package on desktop and have attempted to install with terminal. the result: dpkg: command not found. Is this a permissions problem? I'm running 11.10 and attempting to set myself up to connect via external modem.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to install a package using `apt` or `Software Center`. It installs the package along with all its dependencies. But it needs active connection.

To install a package offline you need to download the package along with all its dependencies on a system where internet connection is available. Next you need to copy the downloads to your offline system in order to install them.

To do this you can go to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and search for `gnome-ppp`. Don't forget to choose correct distribution. Download the `.deb` file with appropriate architecture.

Make sure you have all the dependencies shown in the `gnome-ppp` page already installed in your system. Most probably you need to download and install `wvdial`, other dependencies should already there. Download the `.deb` file for `wvdial` also, if not pre-installed on your system.

To check a package/dependency is installed in your system, run the following command in terminal,

```
dpkg -l | grep <packagename>
```

For example, to check `wvdial` is there or not use,

```
dpkg -l | grep wvdial
```

If you have it on your system the output will be like,

```
ii    wvdial    1.61-4build1    intelligent Point-to-Point Protocol dialer
```

Before you proceed to install check all the dependencies are installed in your system (if not you need to download each of them from the above site and install).

**Installation:**

First you need to install the dependency(s). Then `gnome-ppp` itself. To install a package run in terminal,

```
sudo dkpg -i /path/to/<packagename.deb>
```

Hope this will be helpful.